# Count the String occurance by extracting the data from log file in specified range of time

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I am new to shell scripting and my problem is:-

I wanted to get the count of a string that is occurring in the log file. Since the log file always get updated in every seconds so I need the data of previous 15 minute only not the whole log file.
Lets say for example if I have a log file name I_am_Log and it use to get updated in every second and I have a string called "Hey, How R U" and I want to get the count of this string that is occurring in the log but only in the last 15 minutes.

I don't know a Unix shell scripting that much, so I am not posting any of my effort.

Answer (score 0):

I can do it by using the following the command:-

```
grep -i "Hey, How R U" /path/to/file | wc -l
```

but this command will show the output from the whole file but I just want the output of previous 15 mins...